# Adding spring security to an existing Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I have spent hours to look for answers and fix this problem. But after spending many hours it seems I might need to put this question for help. I saw many similar scenarios but none became an answer.

I already have a spring web application that runs well with out authentication. I  am trying to implement a simple spring security using xml configuration.

[image: Before the update]

Before Modification

[image]

[image]

This Is after Modification

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>course-project</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/core</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tadtab.core"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
</beans>
```

And this is the dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>course-project</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my configuration before updating it with the example I found online.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>course-project</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I used to be able to access my application at calhost:8283/core/

By the time I update web.xml with the following code

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/core</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am getting the following exception

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#60cee7ca' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#60cee7ca': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
.
.
.

    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#60cee7ca' of type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#60cee7ca': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)

.
.
.
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#60cee7ca': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)

    .
    .
    .
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.setCaseSensitive(Z)V
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher$SpringAntMatcher.createMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher$SpringAntMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:252)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher$SpringAntMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:2
```

Comment: This should fix your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662547/context-initialization-failed-nosuchmethoderror-antpathmatcher-setcasesensiti

Comment: Why don't you try pure java based configuration?

Comment: I already have xml based configuration with the existing MVC application. I just want to follow the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used  4.2.1 spring security library
and updated spring security xsd like this

spring-security-4.2.xsd

And was able to see the app running well.